# Galería de imagenes con bootstrap

Tags: php7, bootstrap-4, jquery-ui

Hola: estoy desarrollando una aplicación de tienda, al cargar la galería de productos no me muestra las imágenes en los cuadros donde deben aparecer, cuando abro la vista de inspección los src de la imágenes han sido cargados y el código aparentemente funciona bien, pero las imágenes no se ven, como al ver el div que las contiene, este no tendría la altura necesaria para mostrar la imagen, he tratado de darle alguna solucion pero sigue sin funcionar, en otra aplicación utilizo el mismo metodo y allí si funciona

Boton de llamada a las funciones:

`<button class="boton" type="button" onclick="SelectorTipo(1); CarCat(10);" id="Boton" >Buscar --></button>`

Mi archivo JS:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '../modelador/Conmutador.php',
        type: 'post',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: {
            TipoBusqueda: $('#TipoBusqueda').val(),
            CodigoFuncion: CodigoFuncion
        }
    }).done(
        function(response) {
            $('#divF2').html(response);
        });
}

function CarCat(CodigoFuncion) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../modelador/Conmutador.php',
        type: 'post',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: {
            TipoBusqueda: $('#TipoBusqueda').val(),
            CodigoFuncion: CodigoFuncion
        }
    }).done(
        function(response) {
            $('#Catalogo').html(response);

        });
}
```

este archivo Conmutador.php funciona como un switch

```
switch($_POST["CodigoFuncion"]){
case 1:

        if (isset($_POST["TipoBusqueda"])){
          switch($_POST["TipoBusqueda"]){
            case 1:
              $MenuVer=$Inicio->SeleccionarBusqueda($_POST["TipoBusqueda"]);
              $Opciones='<p class="parag">Agrupamiento</p> <br> <select class="selec1" Name="Menu1" id="selec1" onchange="BuscaRubroGrupo(2)"> <option Value="0" disabled selected>Seleccione el grupo</option>';

              foreach ($MenuVer as $Valor){
                  $Opciones .= '<option value="'.$Valor['Id_Agrupamiento'].'">'.$Valor['DescripcionGrupo'].'</option> ';
              }

              $Opciones.='</Select> <br>';
              echo $Opciones;
              break;

      case 10:
       switch($_POST["TipoBusqueda"]){
         case 1:
            $GalPublicadores="";
            $GalPublicadores=$Inicio->ConsultaDePublicaciones();
            echo $GalPublicadores;
         case 2:
        default:
        }
      default:
}
```

y este archivo php realiza funciona como regla de Negocio

```
class CatalogoProductos{

    static public function SeleccionarBusqueda($TipoBusqueda){
       $DatosCat= new ArchivosdeProductos;

          switch ($TipoBusqueda) {
            case 1:
              $Datos_menu=$DatosCat->ConsultaListaDeAgrupamientos();
              break;
            
            case 2:
              $Datos_menu=$DatosCat->ConsultaListaDeRubros();
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
          return $Datos_menu; 
        }
 static public function ConsultaDeTienda(){
      $DatosCat=new ArchivosdeProductos;
      $Publicadores=$DatosCat->ConsultaListaDePublicaciones();
      
      $Opciones="";
      $Z=0;
      foreach($Publicadores as $Usuario){
        
        $Opciones.='<div class="producto">';


        if(file_exists("../usuarios/".$Usuario["Ac_Nombre_Usuario"]."_".$Usuario["Id_Usuario"]."/personal/")) {

          $Opciones.='<div id="myCarousel'.$Z.'" class="carousel Calesita"  data-bs-ride="carousel">
                      <div class="carousel-indicators Indicadores" >';
          $Z=$Z+1;
          $carpeta='../usuarios/'.$Usuario['Ac_Nombre_Usuario'].'_'.$Usuario['Id_Usuario'].'/personal/';
          $TotalArchivos=count(glob($carpeta.'{*.jpg,*.gif,*.png,*.jpeg}',GLOB_BRACE));
          $CuentaBotones=0;
          while($CuentaBotones<$TotalArchivos){
            $Opciones.='<button type="button"  data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="'. $CuentaBotones.'>" class="active Navegadores"  aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide'.$CuentaBotones.'"></button>';
            $CuentaBotones++;
          }
          $Opciones.='</div>
                      <div class="carousel-inner" >';
          $Archivos=opendir($carpeta);
          
          $ArchFotos=array();
          $I=0;
          while($Fotos=readdir($Archivos)){
            
            $ArchFotos[$I]=$Fotos;
            if ($ArchFotos[$I]!="." && $ArchFotos[$I]!=".."){
              $Opciones.='<div class="carousel-item" >
                            <img  src="'.$carpeta.$ArchFotos[$I].'" class="d-block Box"  alt="'.$ArchFotos[$I].'" />
                            </div>';
              
              $I++;
            }            
          }
        }
        $Opciones.='</div>
                   <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel"      data-bs-slide="prev">
                      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true" style="background-color:darkblue; border-radius:50%;" ></span>
                      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel"  data-bs-slide="next" >
                      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true" style="background-color:darkblue; border-radius:50%%;" ></span>
                      <span class="visually-hidden" >Next</span>
                    </button> 
                  </div>
                  <p>'.$Usuario["Id_Usuario"]."-".$Usuario["Ac_Nombre_Usuario"].'</p>
                  <P>'.$Usuario["Usu_Localidad_2"].'-'.$Usuario["Usu_Distrito_2"].'</p>
                  <p>'.$Usuario["NombreProvincia"].'</p>
               </div>';  

      }
      return $Opciones;
    }
```

aclaro que he probado el código y este funciona bien, el problema es que no muestra las imágenes en miniatura en el html.
Agradeceré a la comunidad cualquier sugerencia